# Is it possible to import a Nuxt package into a VuejS project?

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

I have a serving Nuxt package that reads a configuration from nuxt.config.js.

This one I would like to use in a VueJS project.
Is there a way to import it and read the config from the main.js of a VueJS project?